# Solving Riccati equation $v'=av^2+bv+c$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve Riccati equation

$$
v(t)'=av(t)^2+bv(t)+c
$$

where $a$,$b$,$c$ are real-valued constants. Wolfram|Alpha gives the solution ([here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=v%28t%29%27%3Da*v%28t%29%5E2%2Bb*v%28t%29%2Bc)), but I am not able to reproduce the result.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint:
$$\int\frac{dv}{av^2 + bv + c} = \int dt$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$v(t)'=av(t)^2+bv(t)+c\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{dv(t)}{dt}=av(t)^2+bv(t)+c\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\frac{dv(t)}{dt}}{av(t)^2+bv(t)+c}=1\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\int\left(\frac{\frac{dv(t)}{dt}}{av(t)^2+bv(t)+c}\right)dt=\int 1dt\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b+2av(t)}{\sqrt{-b^2+4ac}}\right)}{\sqrt{-b^2+4ac}}=t+k_1\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\left(t+k_1\right)\left(\sqrt{-b^2+4ac}\right)=2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b+2av(t)}{\sqrt{-b^2+4ac}}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\frac{\left(t+k_1\right)\left(\sqrt{-b^2+4ac}\right)}{2}=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b+2av(t)}{\sqrt{-b^2+4ac}}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\tan\left(\frac{\left(t+k_1\right)\left(\sqrt{-b^2+4ac}\right)}{2}\right)=\tan\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b+2av(t)}{\sqrt{-b^2+4ac}}\right)\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\tan\left(\frac{\left(t+k_1\right)\left(\sqrt{-b^2+4ac}\right)}{2}\right)=\frac{b+2av(t)}{\sqrt{-b^2+4ac}}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\tan\left(\frac{\left(t+k_1\right)\left(\sqrt{-b^2+4ac}\right)}{2}\right)\left(\sqrt{-b^2+4ac}\right)=b+2av(t)\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\tan\left(\frac{\left(t+k_1\right)\left(\sqrt{-b^2+4ac}\right)}{2}\right)\left(\sqrt{-b^2+4ac}\right)-b=2av(t)\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\left(t+k_1\right)\left(\sqrt{-b^2+4ac}\right)}{2}\right)\left(\sqrt{-b^2+4ac}\right)-b}{2a}=v(t)\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$v(t)=\frac{1}{2a}\left(\sqrt{4ac-b^2}\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(k_1\sqrt{4ac-b^2}+t\sqrt{4ac-b^2}\right)\right)-b\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Comment: @student you're welcome!